# ExcelDNA - Reference x64 library for Excel 32 bits

Tags: c#, excel, plugins, 64-bit

I'm writing a .Net 6.0 Excel plugin which will stream Tibco data through Excel.
For that, i'm referencing a x64 Nuget package which will subscribe to a Tibco subject and stream the data.

However when I set my project in x64 and launch it, I get a System.IO.FileLoadException Could not load file or assembly xxx

Which is logical since my Excel is in 32 bits and my plugin is in 64 bits

Is there a workaround for this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: When Excel runs as 32-bit process then at runtime it can load AnyCPU or x86 assemblies but not x64 (probably BadImageFormatException?). I am not sure if understand your question correctly...you simply need the x86 version of your NuGet package. Or you need to switch to 64-bit Excel.